# EN_CHANGE notification for CHtmlEditView

Tags: mfc

I am using `CHtmlEditView` as text editor. I want notification as soon as there is a change in text. `CEdit` control there is `EN_CHANGE` notification. I need something similar for `CHtmlEditView`. On MSDN there is `IPersistStreamInit::IsDirty()` which determines whether an object has changed since it was last saved to its stream.
but not a notification. Is there any similar notification like `EN_CHANGE` ?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s98fh2ze.aspx, consider the onafterupdate event.

Comment: Hans Passant's suggestion is better, but you can also override `CMy_HtmlEditView::OnUpdateUI` then check for `CHtmlEditView::GetIsDirty` (same as `::IsDirty`)

Comment: Thanks, it solved my problem